# Data not being shown on MySql Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am doing a simple program that maps data from an excel file into a mysql DB, using Java and JDBC for that purpose, as well as MySQL Workbench.
I noticed in one of the tables, that even tough the code itself gave no error, when I checked the table via MySQL Workbench nothing appeared on it.
Then I added something manually to that table, and noticed that the autogenerated ids were indeed incrementing.
I ran the code once again, addeds something manually again, and yes, the ids jumped not by one but by several increments.

I am wondering, why is this happening?

For reference purposes, here you have the code

```
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.iterator();


        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(server.getJdbcURL(), server.getUsername(), server.getPassword());
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);


        String courseSql = "INSERT INTO course (begin_date, end_date,itinerary_id,student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";
        PreparedStatement courseStatement = connection.prepareStatement(courseSql);


    //  while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {

            Sheet nextSheet= sheetIterator.next();
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = nextSheet.iterator();

            String itinerary = nextSheet.getSheetName();


            rowIterator.next(); // skip the header row

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {

                Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();

                if (nextRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().isEmpty())
                {
                    break;
                }

                String fullName = nextRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                String studentId = findIdbyfullName(fullName);


                Date limitDate= nextRow.getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
                Long limitDateinLong = limitDate.getTime();

                java.sql.Date limitDateforSQL = new java.sql.Date(limitDateinLong);


                Date initDate= nextRow.getCell(2).getDateCellValue();
                Long initDateinLong = initDate.getTime();

                java.sql.Date initDateforSQL = new java.sql.Date(initDateinLong);


                courseStatement.setDate(1, initDateforSQL);
                courseStatement.setDate(2, limitDateforSQL);

                switch (itinerary)
                {           
                    case "JAVA": courseStatement.setInt(3, 3); break;
                    case "Frontend": courseStatement.setInt (3,2); break;
                    case "Net" : courseStatement.setInt(3,4); break;
                }

                courseStatement.setString(4,studentId);

                courseStatement.addBatch();
                courseStatement.executeBatch();

            }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: well, I thought it was self-explicative enough :) the question is..why? why can this happen?

Comment: I think you are missing `connection.commit()`.